# I am working on a binary classification problem in keras.

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a binary classification problem in keras, and whenever I tune any parameters, add layers, increase depth, the accuracy stays at the same exact value. The training accuracy is stuck at 52.61% I used this as an example: https://medium.com/@pushkarmandot/build-your-first-deep-learning-neural-network-model-using-keras-in-python-a90b5864116d. What could be fundamentally wrong with my code? I will include snippets.

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:11].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = .20)



#Initializing Neural Network
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 10))
# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 5, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, init = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))



# Compiling Neural Network
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


# Fitting our model 
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 20, nb_epoch = 100)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
```

Comment: can you tell us about your dataset? if your dataset has more hidden features, you may want to increase number units in each first and second hidden layers.